# how to add styling to visual force page?

Tags: visualforce

I need help regarding adding style sheets to my visual force page.
Which tags can be used ? I tried using html tags.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_custom.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a new style sheet style.css file and including it in as static resource.. and then referencing it in the visualforce page

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.style_resources, 'styles.css')}"/>
```

for accessing the styles.

the alternative would be to include styles directly in the visualforce page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_custom.htm

Hope this helps!!